# am working on updating a single attribute in the User Model which is the balance attribute,

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

how I can update a single value for an already existing row in the db by only having a parameters that I want to add it to this attribute

here is my code for a trivial way but didnt work

```
      public bool BuyBook(int BookId, int UserId, int BookPrice){        
        using (var ctx = new OnlineBooksEntities())
        {
            User updatedCustomer = (from c in ctx.Users
                                        where c.UserId == UserId
                                        select c).FirstOrDefault();
            updatedCustomer.Balance = BookPrice;
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
        this.DeleteBook(BookId);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What's the error that you are getting? I would recommend that you use `First()` rather than `FirstOrDefault()` so it is obvious if the row *doesn't* exist in the database. But otherwise it looks correct.

Comment: @Felix on ctx.savechanges, no am sure the row exists in the db

Comment: Being "sure" is one of the most common mistakes of a junior developer. If you always expect the row to exist - then definitely use `First()`. Also - you didn't answer my first (*main*) question - What's the error that you are getting

Comment: @Felix yes you are right but the thing is I tracked the row with real values and that why I made sure of its existence, however I found a solution by adjusting an sql query in the mvc

Answer (score 0):

Add an sql query to the method solves the update aim
 public bool BuyBook(int BookId, int UserId, int BookPrice)
        {
            try
            {

```
            using (var ctx = new OnlineBooksEntities())
            {
                User user = ctx.Users.Where(x => x.UserId == UserId).FirstOrDefault();
                BookPrice = (int)user.Balance + BookPrice;
                int noOfRowUpdated = 
                    ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Update Users set Balance = "+BookPrice+ " where UserId ="+UserId);


                }
```

Answer (score -1):

Updating basically means changing an existing row's value.  Since you mentioned EF, you can do this by retrieving the object, changing its value, and saving it back.  Thus you can do something like this:

```
using (var db = new MyContextDB())
{
    var result = db.Books.SingleOrDefault(b => b.BookPrice == bookPrice);
    if (result != null)
    {
        result.SomeValue = "Your new value here";
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: And the commenter was **sure** that he answered your question ;)